# Invalid security context token when using WCF with a Load Balance (AWS)

Tags: c#, wcf, amazon-web-services, load-balancing

I have a WCF application that is hosted on AWS. To achieve a higher availability, I've created a snapshot of the WCF machine and launched another instance with this image.

Also, I've created an Elastic Load Balance (ELB) that routes requests to those 2 servers.

With my WCF Client, I can successfully connect with both servers if I use the machine public IP address. **But if I use the ELB hostname, my connection fails with the following error:**

> System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The message could not be
>   processed. This is most likely because the action
>   'http://tempuri.org/IService/GetCustomerData' is incorrect or because
>   the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or
>   because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context
>   token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to
>   inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions
>   prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's
>   binding.

The error suggests that I have a invalid or expired security token. So, I've checked the Send and Receive timeout and it is already set to 10 minutes: `sendTimeout="00:10:00"`, `receiveTimeout="00:10:00"`
(requests usually takes 5-15 seconds)

My biding configuration:

```xml
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Also, I've double checked:

- ELB and machines Firewall are open on ports 80 and 443.
- My ELB was configured with the correct certificate and has a listener on port 443.
- I have an IIS Web Server on both machines. If I use the ELB address, everything works.
- If the ELB routes to one machine, WCF works. If routes to two machines, WCF fails.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've managed to solve this issue adding the following parameter: `establishSecurityContext="false"`.

```xml
<bindings>
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="wsHttpBinding" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:10:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00" enabled="false" />
      <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" 
                 establishSecurityContext="false"/> <!-- this line -->
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Googling, I've learned that:

When this value is set to **false**, key exchange and validation must be done per call using asymmetric encryption. The default value of this parameter is **true** and that means that the first call will create a security context with asymmetric encryption, but it will be cached and further calls will use only symmetric encryption, that is faster.

Performance consideration: [Yaron Naveh](http://webservices20.blogspot.com.br/2009/01/wcf-performance-gearing-up-your-service.html)

When the client is expected to make many calls in succession, it is better to set this parameter to **true**, BUT with a Load Balance, **calls are routed to different servers and this breaks the message due to invalid token**. So, you must to disable this Security Context feature.

Detailed explanation in *Establishing Security Context* section: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh273122(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Based on your statement that you have the correct certificate installed on the ELB, I'm assuming you are using SSL offloading.  This can be a problem, as the client binding needs to be configured using transport security, but the service will be receiving the request over port 80, so it would need a different binding configuration.

However, WCF requires transport security when you specify client credentials, so you may have to turn off SSL offloading if you need to send client credentials.

Comment: Thanks dan, but I'm not using SSL offloading. My Client, Server and ELB are using only HTTPS. I've managed to find the solution and it was related with the security context. I've posted the answer here.